# Luggage storage at El Alto La Paz airport

Tags: luggage-storage, la-paz, lpb

I am looking for a place to leave 2 pieces of luggage for 3 days in La Paz, Bolivia - preferrably at La Paz El Alto airport (LPB)

Does anybody know if such a service is available there?

If one simply searches the internet, then the answer is yes - it is supposed to be somewhere in the main hall.

However, I was at the airport today, on arrival from Cuzco, Peru. I was specifically looking for this counter/service and was not able to find it. There was a single currency exchange counter, a souvenir shop and a hallway to connecting flights and that was it.

It seems to be a really small airport/terminal and also there is some construction going on - which might be the reason why I could not find it.

The [webpage for the airport](http://www.sabsa.aero/aeropuerto-el-alto/) has been down for weeks and is of no use.

To give an overview of what I saw at the airport - first there were the usual passport check booths, right after the booths there was a single belt, from which we picked up our luggage. Then there was the customs check and finally we were in a relatively smallish hall with exit (to taxis) to the left and the currency exchange to the right of us. Maybe the international arrivals are just separated from everything else?

Does anyone know now for sure that this service really does exist as of December 2014? Maybe I did not look for it long and hard enough - if that is the case - where exactly would it be located?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We went back to look for it and there really is one - on the left hand side immediately after entering departures hall.

Storing one piece of luggage for 24 hours costs 25 Bs

Note that the above information is correct as of January 2015, a new terminal is under construction and things might change once that is completed.